# JSF2.2 カスタムコンポーネントの終了タグのレンダリングについて

Tags: html5, java8, jsf

掲題の件に関して、link要素のカスタムコンポーネントを作成したいです。(JSF標準のHtmlOutputLink.javaを継承したカスタムコンポーネントを作成するつもりです。)

仕様を満たすためには、
継承したクラスにてResponseWriterWrapperインスタンスを生成し、startElementメソッド/endElementメソッドをオーバーライドし、開始タグをa要素→link要素に置き換え、終了タグはレンダリングしないよう制御する(endElementメソッド内で何もせずにreturnする)必要があるかと思います。

実際に上記のコーディングを試してみたのですが、タグの終わりに"/"が付与されてしまいます。
(という風に)

HTML5の仕様上、link要素の末尾が"/>"となる事に問題がない事は承知しておりますが、"/"を出力しないことは不可能でしょうか?

(もっと効率の良いlink要素のカスタムコンポーネントの作り方は無数にあるかと思いますが、どうしても"/"がついてしまう原因を追及できなかった為諦めきれません。。。)

実装ソース等を用意しておらず恐縮ではありますが、回答のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 継承したクラスのソースコードを見せて下さい。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/87531